# how to split query expression result attributes by their entity

Tags: linq, split, attributes, entity

I have some big query with 8 joins and I want to go over each entity attributes in the query expression result for duplicate those entities.
I've tried to split the result attributes but I'm not sure how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you may be looking for the **OfType** linq method?